# What is the physical significance of a complete boolean function

Tags: digital-logic

As per the definition,

A boolean function is said to be complete if

- It derived all the basic operations
- It reduces to another function that is already known to be functionally complete.

What inferences can be draw in light of this definition and what exactly do we mean by a functionally complete boolean function.

Comment: Without some context : it's meaningless. If this is part of a course, reference the course and textbook you are using in the question.

Comment: Generally, if you want help with coursework or similar, you need to ask something much more specific. You generally won't get an easy answer to the original question here. If there is a detail which you don't understand, ask about the detail and show you understand the rest.

Comment: Your title question, and your final question don't match.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of the expression "functionally complete" before so I looked it up.

> From the point of view of digital electronics, functional completeness means that every possible logic gate can be realized as a network of gates of the types prescribed by the set. In particular, all logic gates can be assembled from either only binary NAND gates, or only binary NOR gates. *Source: Wikipedia, [Functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).*

As an example, every logic gate can be assembled using the set {OR, AND, NOT}. We can do better than this though. Just using the set {NAND} we can create all the others:

[image]

*Figure 1. Using only NAND gates we can construct NOT, AND and OR. NAND and NOR can be created by adding a NOT. NOR, XOR, XNOR and others can also be created.*

In this sense the set {NAND} is functionally complete. The set {NOR} is similarly functionally complete. As a result these were most common gates used in discrete logic and also had the advantage of very short propagation time.

See Wikipedia's [NAND logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic) and [NOR logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que quiere decir , es que si usted armo correctamente la funcion booleana sin simplificar , al simplificarla correctamente  con el algebra de boole usted va a obtener la misma función con las mismas características de la primera .

What that means is that if you armo correctly the function boolean without simplify , to simplify correctly with the algebra boole you are going to obtain the same function with the same characteristics of the first (functionally complete).

Comment: Google gives a better translation than you do - but you do not address the question. Answers are supposed to be in English, I think (although I was unable to find a reference to confirm this).